# change string on the fly in for loop

Tags: python

```
s = 'abcd'

for i in s:
    s = s[:-1]
    print(i)
    print('s is',s)
```

result:

```
a
s is abc
b
s is ab
c
s is a
d
s is
```

in each iteration, s is changed by dropping the last char. I assume a new string is created and s is pointed to the new string each iteration, but why the loop is over the old string. There should be no reference pointed to the old string of 'abcd' after the first iteration and end up being collected by garbage collector, right? please point out where I misunderstand.

Comment: The for loop is still iterating over the original `s`.

Comment: can you explain why? since there should be  no reference pointed to the original string, how its able to be found.

Comment: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html - this is part of the answer.

Comment: IMHO the duplicate link has a very complex question, and thus a complex answer. This question is minimal at least.@StephenRauch maybe you can suggest a better duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

> s is changed by dropping the last char

Well, yes and no. , As you have assigned to `s` with

```
s = s[:-1]
```

now `s` name points to a new string, but the original string (the one you're iterating upon) is still somewhere, referenced by the `for` loop internal iterator and thus not garbage collectable until when the loop ends.

Note that since strings are immutable, there's no way you can change the original `s` as referenced in the loop, as opposed to a `list` where slice assignment (`s[:] = s[:-1]`, or just `s.pop()`) would allow you to (and that would modify the list while iterating upon and would also be wrong, even if here removing the last element doesn't have the strange effect you have when removing an element in the middle)